# Logout from secure single page with php sessions

Tags: php

I'm securing single page with session:

```
if($username === 'admin' && $password === 'admin1'){
    $_SESSION['secured'] = "Secured";
    header('LOCATION:admin/approve.php'); //go to location after successful login.
    die();
}
```

In approve page I'm checking if session is set:

```
session_start(); //starting session to acces to it

if(!isset($_SESSION['secured'])){
  exit();
}
```

I made a logout button that redirect to site index, but after logout when I'm tring to reach the secure page i dont have problem to enter, and session is still set.
Logout code:

```
unset($_SESSION); //clear session array
session_destroy(); //Destroy session
unset($_SESSION['secured']);
header("Location: ../index.html");
```

Comment: how to [destroy a session](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) - check out example #1

Comment: Seems problem solved 10x

Answer (score 0):

You mean the approve page?

What I see is that you did not specify where the page should exit to...
Maybe you should try something like this:

```
session_start(); //starting session to acces to it

if(!isset($_SESSION['secured'])){
  header("Location: ../index.html");
  exit();
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: No. The problem is in the logout page but it seems the first comment example solved it. 10x